# jQuery Modal Dialog works fine on the first page after refresh, but not on any other pages after that unless refreshed

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, dialog, modal-dialog

Alright, so I have this jQuery modal dialog to remind non-registered users to sign up if they try to access user-only actions. After refresh, the dialog works fine and can be closed and opened indefinitely... On **THAT** page. As soon as the page is switched the modal doesn't work unless the page is refreshed again.

I have the modal tied to rails **if else** statement such as

```
<% if signed_in? %>
  <a href="User only page">
<% else %>
  <div class="modalstart">
<& end %>
```

**HOWEVER**, I tried it without the statement, and the problem persisted, so I'm guessing this is jQuery problem.

Here's my code for the modal dialog code:

```
$(window).bind("load", function() {
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#modalresult').dialog({ width: 550, height: 300, autoOpen: false, modal: true,   
                                                               resizable: false });

  $( ".modalstart" ).click(function() {
    $( "#modalresult" ).dialog( "open" );
    return false;
   });
  })
});
```

And the div that the dialog is tied to is set not to display until called, if it's of any consequence:

```
<div id="modalresult" style="display:none"></div>
```

The modal box has a signup form and the reqular X to close it off.

I'm thinking, could it be that jQuery somehow thinks the modal is already in use when the user switches the page? Thanks in advance for any help or ideas.

Comment: Be sure to $( "#modalresult" ).dialog( "close" ); on any option user has to close the modal (close method for jquery UI dialog) or it will assume its already opened.

Comment: you don't need this line $(window).bind("load", function() {

Comment: I'm just confused as to which action to bind the close event. I attempted `$( ".ui-dialog-titlebar-close" ).click(function() {
        $( "#modalresult" ).dialog( "close" );
    });`
which I believe is the default modal close div, but the problem persisted. It opens up as many times as one wants on one page, but stops working altogether when redirected to some other page.

// Edit: Thanks for pointing that out Michael. I read up on it and `$(document).ready(function()` achieves basically the same thing.

Comment: Strange. Does the console show anything? Did you try to place a breakpoint or log to console and see what parts of the code are executed? I don't suppose you have an accessible example deployed somewhere.

Comment: Server console showed only the WEBrick bug ("Could not determine content length..."), but I got a new version and fixed it. Didn't fix the main problem, though. I have never used either of those, but I would gladly submit a log to fix this problem. One other thing, is it normal that the console shows the `Started GET "/assets/modal.js"` only when you refresh a page, but not when you navigate to a new page? Or is that unnecessary for new pages? I'm starting to believe the jQuery in my app doesn't carry to new pages, because you don't need to use the modal at all for it not to work after that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alright, so turns out turbolinks (rails 4.0) was somehow interfering with the jQuery code, blocking `$(document).ready()` from executing. This led jQuery to not work on any subsequent pages where the user navigated after refresh.

The solution was this gem https://github.com/kossnocorp/jquery.turbolinks

I'm leaving this for others who have the same problem to save time.

Big thanks to all who attempted at helping. I hugely appreciate it.

Comment: Ah, yeah, I had some issues with turbolinks in with my Rails 4 app too! Forgot that it's on by default. Good to hear you resolved your issue.

Answer (score 0):

As it looks like you're sticking with the default jQueryUI behavior (e.g., you're closing the dialog with the built-in 'x'), I think just a cleanup of your javascript will have this working fine. That `$(window).bind("load", function() {` is definitely causing some issues I think.

**JS**

```
$(function() {
    $('#modalresult').dialog({
        width: 550, 
        height: 300, 
        autoOpen: false, 
        modal: true,
        resizable: false 
    });

    $('.modalstart').click(function() {
        $('#modalresult').dialog('open');
    });
});
```

You shouldn't have to do any other event binding, jQuery UI will "just work".

While it doesn't simulate you're exact situation, I created a simple fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/chucknelson/WVmx6/

The window.bind breaks it, and I'm thinking your specific problem might be related to that.

Comment: While the window bind turned out to be completely useless, it doesn't seem to be the issue. Similarly I don't think the modal close/open is the problem either, because the modal doesn't seem to work on any subsequent page after refresh even if it hasn't been used even once. That concludes something essential changes on the subsequent pages, but I can't get around what it is, because it's all essentially the same. Could it be that jQuery somehow loads only for the first page in my rails app?